# can this sql query be simplified?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. MySql

users  : A_ID,name
event :  B_ID, A_ID,cat_id,date

Now I want to get all users , who participated more at events on a given period of time, and need to add based on category too. I am doing something like this :

```
select name from users ,
 (select A_id, count(*) 
  from   event 
  where date<=givendate
 group by A_id
 order by count(*) desc ) e
 where users.A_id=e.a_id
 limit 0,5
```

Is there any easy and prof way to write that script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks OK apart from a few minor points:

- Your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` should be in the outer select otherwise the order of the results is indeterminate.
- Use the `JOIN` keyword to join two tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users AS u
JOIN
(
    SELECT A_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM event
    WHERE date <= givendate
    AND cat_id = 42
    GROUP BY A_id
) AS e
USING (A_id)
ORDER BY e.cnt DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: thanks, I will try it, is there any way to check if date is inside past week dates with sql ?

Comment: @SamirMemmedov: You'll have to first figure out how your weeks are defined. That depends on where you live and what rules your calendar follows. Different countries have different rules. You may want to take a look at the [`WEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) or [`WEEKOFYEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) functions and see if one of those suits your needs.